# Unable to make angular-isotope work for my layout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-isotope

I'm new to AngularJS which I'm using to build a photo gallery. I'm also trying to use angular-isotope for my layout but I'm unable to make it work.

I have included the isotope and angular-isotope JS files:

> ```
> <script src="bower_components/outlayer/item.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/outlayer/outlayer.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/masonry/masonry.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/isotope/js/item.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/isotope/js/layout-mode.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/isotope/js/isotope.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/isotope/js/layout-modes/vertical.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/isotope/js/layout-modes/fit-rows.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/isotope/js/layout-modes/masonry.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-isotope/dist/angular-isotope.js"></script>
> ```

The following HTML markup:

```
<div isotope-container ng-cloak id="isotopeContainer" class="isotope stream ng-cloak" ng-controller="PhotosCtrl">
   <article isotope-item class="photo" ng-repeat="photo in photosList">
      <a no-click href="#">
         <img lazyload ng-src="images/transparent.gif" data-original="{{photo.url}}" alt="{{photo.title}}">
      </a>
   </article>
</div>
```

And my photo.js (controller):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ng1stApp')
  .controller('PhotosCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/photosList').success(function(photosList) {
        $scope.photosList = photosList;
    });
  })
    .directive('lazyload', function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $(element).lazyload({
            effect: 'fadeIn',
            effectspeed: 500,
            'skip_invisible': false
          });
        }, 0);
      }
    };
  })
    .directive('noClick', function() {
        return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element(element).on('click',function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log('links are disabled');
        });
      }
    };
});
```

But no luck. What am I missing? I've looked at the example at http://mankindsoftware.github.io/angular-isotope/ but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Hard to say with just a code review. I have never used angular-isotope, but I have used Isotope with Angular without a wrapper. Are you seeing any errors? Are any of your elements getting decorated with Isotope classes? A simplified [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) could go a long way as far as convincing people here to help you goes.

Comment: @MarcKline No errors, no isotope classes either. :-/

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I came across it while searching for something else. I think I have just dealt with the same issue as you, and solved it by adding iso.directives as a dependancy:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [
   'iso.directives'
]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's very basic angular, but should still be in the Angular-Isotope documentation.